# malformed url exception

Tags: java, url

```
https://twitter.com/sessions?authenticity_token=b1b43178e09c1e6ccec1b3183f1f139f39643aaf&session%5Busername_or_email%5D=ddddd&session%5Bpassword%5D=rrrrr&q=&site_action=https%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2Fsessions&serialized_string=Hello
```

why is this url throwing a `java.net.MalformedURLException`??

Comment: Works fine here. Your problem lies somewhere else. Please post the **entire** stacktrace along an SSCCE (http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason I can think of is if your code is mistakenly applying the URL decoder to the URL string before trying to parse the URL.  That would replace the %xx escapes with the characters they stand for, and you'd end up with illegal characters in the "query" part of the URL.

Please post the code that throws the exception.

Comment: That was also the first I thought, but all those urlencoded characters lies in the ASCII range.

Comment: URL x=new URL("the_above_posted_url");
this line is throwing the java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: the_above_posted_url
also fyi i am running the code on google app engine just in case it makes a difference.

Comment: sorry guys it was just that i had the string name in the double qoutes..really sorry to bother you.